# For a triangle $ABC$, $a^2+b^2+c^2=8R^2$ then it is a right triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

$ABC$ is a triangle, $a^2+b^2+c^2=8R^2$ then how do we prove it is a right triangle?

Comment: What does that `R`  stand for?

Comment: @BabakS. it is the circumradius

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use the well-known formula $R = \frac{abc}{4A}$, where $A$ is the area of the triangle.
Thus $8R^2 = \frac{8a^2b^2c^2}{16A^2}$, and by Heron's formula
$$16A^2 = (a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c).$$
Now assume that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 8R^2$. Then we have
$$8a^2b^2c^2 - (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c) = 0.$$
Expanding this gives
$$a^6 + b^6 + c^6 - a^2b^4 - b^2c^4 - c^2a^4 - a^4b^2 - b^4c^2 - c^4a^2 + 2 a^2 b^2 c^2 = 0,$$
which can be factored as
$$(a^2 + b^2 - c^2)(b^2 + c^2 - a^2)(c^2 + a^2 - b^2) = 0.$$
Thus the claim follows from Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $R$ means circumradius we can use the formula

$$R=\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{8(1+\cos A\cos B\cos C)}},$$

where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the sidelengths and $A$, $B$, and $C$ are the angles. Plugging in $a^2+b^2+c^2=8R^2$, we reduce the above to

$$1+\cos A\cos B\cos C=1,$$

whence one of $\cos A$, $\cos B$, or $\cos C$ must be $0$ - meaning that we have a right triangle.

Comment: How do you prove the formula?

Comment: @125a8owp Well, you can reduce it to the familiar form $R=\dfrac{abc}{4\triangle}$ by using the law of cosines and then some not-completely-awful,-but-still-not-particularly-fun algebraic manipulation. However, as is the nature of such formulae, it is nice just to know it and then be able to pull it out of one's hat when the appropriate problem (such as this one) arises. (I do not claim this is the simplest method of proof)

Comment: I have a found a proof :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be the area of the triangle.

Since we have $4RS=abc$ and
$$\begin{align}16S^2&=(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)\\&=-(a^4+b^4+c^4)+2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)\end{align}$$
if $a^2+b^2+c^2=8R^2$, then we have
$$\begin{align} 0 &=\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{R^2}-8\\&=\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{a^2b^2c^2}(-a^4-b^4-c^4+2a^2b^2+2b^2c^2+2c^2a^2)-8\\&=\frac{(-a^2+b^2+c^2)(a^2-b^2+c^2)(a^2+b^2-c^2)}{a^2b^2c^2}.\end{align}$$
$$\Rightarrow (-a^2+b^2+c^2)(a^2-b^2+c^2)(a^2+b^2-c^2)=0$$
So, the triangle has to be a right triangle.

**P.S.** Actually, $a^2+b^2+c^2=8R^2\iff\text{The triangle $ABC$ is a right triangle}$.

Also, we can see the followings :
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\gt 8R^2\iff \text{The triangle $ABC$ is an acute‐angled triangle}.$$
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\lt 8R^2\iff \text{The triangle $ABC$ is an obtuse triangle}.$$